# Whats the difference between Methods and Members in C++?

Tags: c++, methods, member

This is a beginner question. I'm pretty sure many people had this doubt but I still didn't find something to clearfy my mind, maybe I'm looking in the wrong direction or conception. The thing is, I can work with both codes:

```
    sf::Clock clock;
    clock.getElapsedTime();

    sf::Clock getElapsedTime();
```

Both are accepted through the IDE but I can't really understand the difference. As I already programm other languages I do know that `clock.getElapsedTime();` will return the time during the app open, but what does `sf::Clock getElapsedTime();` do exactly?

thanks in advance

Comment: This calls for a [book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1168156)

Comment: You're mixing idioms here. If you do OO, objects have "methods" and "attributes". In C++, classes have "members" that are either "member functions" or "member data".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First **calls** a member function `getElapsedTime` through object named `clock` while,
the second just **declares** a non-member (free) function by name `getElapsedTime` which returns a object of type `sf::Clock` and takes no arguments.

Good Read:
[What is a function declaration?](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=what%20is%20a%20function%20declaration%20c%2b%2b&oq=what%20is%20a%20function%20declaration%20c%2b%2b&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.5256j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 2):

*"what does `sf::Clock getElapsedTime();` do exactly?"*

It declares the function named `getElapsedTime` that takes no arguments and returns the value (an object) of type `sf::Clock`.

Answer (score 1):

```
     sf::Clock getElapsedTime();
```

declares a function getElapsedTime() which returns a `sf::Clock` object. You need (or somebody else) to define this function somewhere else though.